# Cannot get Web Sockets to work with virtual IP redirection

Tags: socket, virtual-ip

I can't get Web Sockets to work on my site when I access it via its virtual IP. If I use it's real (intranet) IP, everything works perfectly. If I use the virtual IP, I get this on Google Chrome console:

```
SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://123.456.78.9/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=0vWQGMzm6Hb59MMbQIEPODQnjqUUxAMmiITaNHUZYZ1tfAK%2FQvXCVDRNll0y4vQkzNcSdK7smLN%2FzCRFtK7AWogA%2FjfwNt47eUu%2F7TdwFYUZCkZlQMP8xqkaY5kfA0oO9N2F5tQYBGedapl3YxHjNQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22jobhub%22%7D%5D&tid=3'. 
SignalR: Closing the Websocket.
```

And I get this on MSIE:

```
SCRIPT12031: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12031, The connection with the server was reset
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to fix this the load balancer needs to be configured specifically for Web Sockets (eventually it'll be by default). How to do this depends on the manufacturer, here's the link for NetScaler:

http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/ns-system-10-map/ns-ac-config-websock-tsk.html